# I have implement OG tags but FB OG debugger doesn't recognize them

Tags: facebook, jekyll, facebook-opengraph, jekyll-bootstrap

This is my code (based on Jekyll Bootstrap):

```
<!-- open graph tags for facebook -->

<meta property="og:title" content='{{ page.title }}' />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ site.title }}" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://blog.obudget.org{{ page.url }}" />

<meta property="og:description" content="{{ page.description }}" />

<meta property="og:type" content="article" />

<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/hasadna.org.il/" />

<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/hasadna.org.il/" />
```

This is what facebook debugger returns:

- Inferred Property    The 'og:url' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property    The 'og:title' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property    The 'og:description' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property    The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: There is no OG tag on http://blog.obudget.org

Comment: it's on http://paperboydesignlab.github.io/2015/10/31/2015_001/

Comment: That site says it’s `og:url` is `http://blog.obudget.org/2015/10/31/2015_001`, and so the second URL is the one Facebook will try to fetch the meta data from.